# Stanford's CoreNLP inconsistency with online demo

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using the latest version [3.8.0] of CoreNLP with the python wrapper [py-corenlp] and I realized there is some inconsistency between the output I get from CoreNLP when I do the annotation with the following annotators: *tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse*, and the output from the [Online Demo](http://corenlp.run). What is more, Stanford's Parser, both when calling it in my code or when I run it online, is giving me the same results as CoreNLP.

For instance, I have the following question (borrowed from the Free917 question corpus):

> at what institutions was Marshall Hall a professor

Using CoreNLP I get the following parsing:

(ROOT\n  (SBAR\n    (WHPP (IN at)\n      (WHNP (WDT what)))\n    (S\n      (NP (NNS institutions))\n      (VP (VBD was)\n        (NP\n          (NP (NNP Marshall) (NNP Hall))\n          (NP (DT a) (NN professor)))))))

Same with Stanford's Parser:

[Tree('ROOT', [Tree('SBAR', [Tree('WHPP', [Tree('IN', ['at']), Tree('WHNP', [Tree('WP', ['what'])])]), Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NNS', ['institutions'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBD', ['was']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NNP', ['Marshall']), Tree('NNP', ['Hall'])]), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['a']), Tree('NN', ['professor'])])])])])])])]

The Online Demo is the correct version though:

[Online Demo Parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmG2Q.png)

How can I get the results I get using the Online Demo?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The demo runs the shift-reduce parser, which is both faster and more accurate, at the expense of a [much] larger serialized model size. See https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml